# How can i make list in class, Python

Tags: python

I want to ask a question.

I made a `ClassName.py` and it has `'list Variable'` like `number = []`.

And I push variables at list and make class objects which is list too in main function.

But now I am faced with a problem.

For example I make a `object1` and it has list variable. After make `object2` it has same variable `object1`. (`object1` -> list Variable = `[1,2,3,4,5]` , `object2` -> list Variable = `[1,2,3,4,5]`)

More detailed, I want to add a `'6'` to `object2` list. If I add `'6'` at `object2` list the `object1` list has added `'6'` too.

I don't know how I can solve the problem.

Plz. Give an advice

Comment: ....uhh.... wat

Comment: Can you please show the actual code that replicates the problem you are experiencing please? It is not very clear what the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: It sounds like you need to read up on Python classes, because I think this problem could be fixed with a well-placed `self.` in front of some variable names.

Comment: I'm sorry. here is my github, https://github.com/dldudwo0805/DeepLearningPractice

Comment: Please copy some of the relevant class code into your question text. It'll make it way easier for any future readers who come upon this page looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you put the variables to be class-level. Thus, all the instances **share** the value of those variables.
To solve this, put the `list` variables inside `__init__(self)`, like this:

```
class YourClassName:
    #Don't put it here!
    def __init__(self):
        self.your_list_name = [] #Put it here
```

Comment: and how can i add the variable?

Comment: Thx.. I solve the problem.... Thank you so much

Comment: That's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The repository you linked has code that looks like this.

```
class Foo:
    a = 1
    b = 2
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

This is creating class variables called `a` and `b`. If you're familiar with a language like Java, this is the nearest equivalent of static variables in other languages. What you want is an instance variable, and we always prefix those with `self.`, as well as defining them *within* `__init__`, not at class scope.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand what you said. I make 'class', and make '__init__(self):' like you said. If you saw my code, see the 'x_point', 'y_point', and 'data_type', there is list variable, so i want to add data at them. if  I make 3 class object, all class object has same list variable. This is the problem